# Temporarily changing document class in LaTeX/resetting pdfLaTeX

Tags: latex, pdflatex

How can I temporarily cause pdfLaTeX to forget everything that I've told it and start with a new document class?

I've modified the example environment from the lshort document:

```
\newwrite\examplesx@out
\newenvironment{examplesx}{%
  \begingroup% Lets Keep the Changes Local
    \@bsphack
    \immediate\openout \examplesx@out \jobname.exa
    \let\do\@makeother\dospecials\catcode`\^^M\active
    \def\verbatim@processline{%
      \immediate\write\examplesx@out{\the\verbatim@line}}%
    \verbatim@start
  }{%
  \immediate\closeout\examplesx@out\@esphack\endgroup%
  \noindent\makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}%
      \small\verbatiminput{\jobname.exa}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hspace*{0.1\textwidth}%
    \framebox{%
      \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}%
        \small\input{\jobname.exa}%
      \end{minipage}
    }%
  }\vspace*{\parskip}%
}
```

and it mostly works, but I want to be able to do something like

```
\begin{examplesx}
\section{Section}
\end{examplesx}
```

and have it show up as a section in a box.  I also would like it to typeset lists using the standard `article` style, even if I use it in `beamer`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way of doing this is to compile some small document and then include the resultant pdf as an image into the larger document. Much simpler even if not exactly what you want. I have done this to show, in a Beamer presentation, what LaTeX articles look like.

Of course if its a REALLY simple document (e.g., a simple block of text) that you want to have inside beamer, I could recommend that you mimic the document with a TikZ "picture" that contains some text.

Comment: As a sidenote, not being able to change classes mid-doc is what I have against the `memoir` class. It has many features that users like, but you have to use it as your class. These features should be (and many actual can be found) as other packages, so they can be used in standard or even other, perhaps required, document classes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another approach: instead of trying to typeset things in beamer as if they would be done in article, simply typeset them with the article document class and include the result the in the beamer document.

With `tcolorbox` this can be done automatically:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{tcblisting}{
    comment only,
  pdf comment,
  compilable listing,
  run pdflatex,
}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Section Title}
test
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```